# Insert JSON object as an argument in Python (Escape the Quote)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to pass a JSON object as an argument to a python2 script, it works but the final json data has a single quote (') enclosing the object.

Below is my code

```
import json
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
data_str = sys.argv[1].decode('string-escape')

print data_str
# The above print's fine with no single quotes

json_data= {
    "server-name": "servername",
    "transaction-id": "transaction_id",
    "user-id": "user_id",
    "change-id": "change_id",
    "consumer-name": "consumer_name",
    "platform": "platform",
    "cookbooks": [
        {
            "cookbook-name": "cookbook_name",
            "cookbook-version": "cookbook_version",
            "recipe-name": "receipie_name",
            "attributes": {

            }
        }
                ]
            }
json_data["cookbooks"][0]["attributes"] = data_str.decode('string-escape')

print json_data["cookbooks"]
```

> Execution

```
C:\Python26\python.exe saver.py "{apple:newf,mango:newb}" 
 {apple:newf,mango:newb} 
{apple:newf,mango:newb} 
[{'cookbook-name': 'cookbook_name', 'cookbook-version': 'cookbook_version', 'recipe-name': 'receipie_name', 'attributes': '{apple:newf,mango:newb}'}]
```

From the above output the final json_data contains quotes in the attribute value
'attributes': **'**{apple:newf,mango:newb}**'** which is causing error in my GET call. 
**How to escape this single quote. ?**

Comment: we dont understand your question yet i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm wrong but I think you've got mixed up with converting the argument string type and decoding a json string.

The single quotes in your result means that the entire value is a string.

Firstly the argument you are passing in on the command line isn't valid JSON.

Try starting your program like this:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe saver.py "{\"apple\":\"newf\",\"mango\":\"newb\"}"
```

Then later decode the JSON contained in the string like this:

```
json_data["cookbooks"][0]["attributes"] = json.loads(data_str)
```

i.e. json.loads and not str.decode

at this point the variable "json_data" isn't holding JSON it's holding a dictionary

You would then have to encode the entire of json_data to pass it in some raw form of http GET unless you have some API doing it for you. Something like

```
encoded_json_data = json.dumps(json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with JSON then use the `json` module built in to your Python. Don't try to fudge the issue by treating it as Python string data when it isn't.

```
import json
```

then:

```
json_data["cookbooks"][0]["attributes"] = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
```

Then if you want to output your Python data structure as json:

```
print(json.dumps(json_data["cookbook"]))
```